# Play video in Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: objective-c, video, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, avfoundation

What is the simplest way to play a video programmatically with Objective-C in Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)? And if I want to support OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) too?

I noticed that iOS [AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188) was introduced to OS X 10.7. Unfortunately the documentation seems to be written for iOS and I found it confusing.

Comment: When Apple makes recommendations, they almost invariably recommend the newest and shiniest API, especially when it makes it easy to port code between OS X and iOS. Is that what you're asking for by "recommended"? Or are you asking for other developers' personal experiences? Because you'll get a very different answer in that case (probably involving QTKit and/or CoreAnimation, but it depends on exactly what you want to do).

Comment: Other developer's personal experiences. I'll rephrase to "simplest".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Simplest" depends on exactly what you're trying to do. If you want more control (e.g., rendering the movie as an OpenGL texture) or less (e.g., a completely independent window that you can just pop up and ignore), there might be different answers.

But for most use cases, if you want 10.6+ support, the simplest way to show a movie is QTKit. See the article "Using QTKit for Media Playback" in the Xcode documentation for a good starting point.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a NSView subclass that plays a video given a URL, using AV Foundation (thus Mac OS X 10.7 upwards only). Based on the [AVSimplePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVSimplePlayerOSX/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011060) sample code.

Header:

```
@interface RMVideoView : NSView

@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) AVPlayer* player;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) AVPlayerLayer* playerLayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL* videoURL;

- (void) play;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
static void *RMVideoViewPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay = &RMVideoViewPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay;
static void *RMVideoViewPlayerItemStatusContext = &RMVideoViewPlayerItemStatusContext;

@interface RMVideoView()

- (void)onError:(NSError*)error;
- (void)onReadyToPlay;
- (void)setUpPlaybackOfAsset:(AVAsset *)asset withKeys:(NSArray *)keys;

@end

@implementation RMVideoView

@synthesize player = _player;
@synthesize playerLayer = _playerLayer;
@synthesize videoURL = _videoURL;

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.wantsLayer = YES;
        _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"player.currentItem.status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:RMVideoViewPlayerItemStatusContext];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [self.player pause];
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"player.currentItem.status"];
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playerLayer.readyForDisplay"];
    [_player release];
    [_playerLayer release];
    [_videoURL release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) setVideoURL:(NSURL *)videoURL {
    _videoURL = videoURL;

    [self.player pause];
    [self.playerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.videoURL];
    NSArray *assetKeysToLoadAndTest = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"playable", @"hasProtectedContent", @"tracks", @"duration", nil];
    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:assetKeysToLoadAndTest completionHandler:^(void) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            [self setUpPlaybackOfAsset:asset withKeys:assetKeysToLoadAndTest];
        });
    }];
}

#pragma mark - KVO

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == RMVideoViewPlayerItemStatusContext) {
        AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
        switch (status) {
            case AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown:
                break;
            case AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay:
                [self onReadyToPlay];
                break;
            case AVPlayerItemStatusFailed:
                [self onError:nil];
                break;
        }
    } else if (context == RMVideoViewPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay) {
        if ([[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue]) {
            self.playerLayer.hidden = NO;
        }
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}


#pragma mark - Private

- (void)onError:(NSError*)error {
    // Notify delegate 
}

- (void)onReadyToPlay {
    // Notify delegate
}

- (void)setUpPlaybackOfAsset:(AVAsset *)asset withKeys:(NSArray *)keys {
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([asset statusOfValueForKey:key error:&error] == AVKeyValueStatusFailed) {
            [self onError:error];
            return;
        }
    }

    if (!asset.isPlayable || asset.hasProtectedContent) {
        [self onError:nil];
        return;
    }

    if ([[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count] != 0) { // Asset has video tracks
        _playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
        self.playerLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;
        self.playerLayer.autoresizingMask = kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable;
        self.playerLayer.hidden = YES;
        [self.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playerLayer.readyForDisplay" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:RMVideoViewPlayerLayerReadyForDisplay];
    }

    // Create a new AVPlayerItem and make it our player's current item.
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];  
}

#pragma mark - Public

- (void) play {
    [self.player play];
}

@end
```

Comment: Since the OP wants to support 10.6, this isn't very helpful. But he did also ask for un-confusion about AVFoundation.

Comment: @abarnert I'm the OP. I wanted to complement your answer with the AV Foundation way.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you probably know what the OP wants quite a bit better than I do. :)